# Getting size of 40k paths from remote network

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, disk-usage, rsh

I've around 40k lines of file with paths which I need to take size from remote site (using `rsh` & `du -scL` command). I tried with `while read line` but due to remote connection, it exits after 100+ lines. So I tried to copy all the lines in to a file with `du -scL` and input the file in to one `rsh` but again it's crashed saying 'command too long'. I need to do a script which calc the size of all these paths from remote site using `rsh` and `du`.

```
#!bin/bash
for line in `cat $destbang1`
do
  rsh vnc.<remotesite> du -sL $line | awk '{print $1}' >> /tmp/size1.txt
done
total=`gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum}' /tmp/size1.txt`
echo $total
```

Comment: You would be better served using find with the exec flag and so something like find -type d -exec du '{}' \;

Comment: Thanks Raman for the suggestion.But does that can process 40k lines in du via rsh? .I  tried while read with -exec and crashed in 100-200 lines.I also tried something like rsh <remotemachine> du -scL `cat /file/which/contain/40kpath/lists.txt` but it exited with "command too long"

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using ssh.

Comment: Don't do 100 rsh or ssh commands without any delay between them;  each one creates a socket that remains unavailable for a few minutes after it's closed, and if enough of these build up you won't be able to make any more connections for awhile. Instead, get the script working on your local system, show us the code, and we'll help you copy it and execute it on the remote system.

Comment: #!/bin/bash  more /tmp/test.txt | while read line do rsh vnc.remote du -sL --total $line >> /tmp/total.txt done total=`gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum}' /tmp/total.txt` echo $total

Comment: Can you copy the script and its input file to the remote system and then do `rsh vnc.remote /path/to/script` ?

Comment: Is RAth short for "Ratheesh P"? If so why do we have to have your name under a post twice?

Comment: If you are asked for code then do not show it in a comment; add it to your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` for creating several `rsh` calls with a low enough number or arguments.

Assuming the remot and local limit are the same:

```
xargs --delimiter='\n' rsh /path/to/script.sh <lists.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run the entire process with a single `rsh` remote shell:

```
tr '\012' '\0' < "$destbang1" |
    rsh vnc.remotesite du -sL --files0-from=- |
    awk '{sum += $1} END {print sum}'
```

This requires that your `du` command understands the `--files0-from` option and that none of the file names in your `$deskbang1` file contains an embedded newline.